# Matching and updating attributes in 2 xmls

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to update attribute's value in xml with attribute from another xml by matching attributes in both xmls.

xml1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <List prodId="123456" sellId="">        
        </List>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

xml2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <info prodId="123456" sellId="121">         
            <qnty>4</qnty>
        </info>
        <info prodId="23456" sellId="890">          
            <qnty>1</qnty>
        </info>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I need to  node, in second xml by prodId attribute, and from that node I need to take the attribute sellId="890" and populate in first xml.

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <List prodId="123456" sellId="890">        
        </List>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

This is my xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="f1" select="'xml2.xml'"/>    
  <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($f1)"/>  

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="Products/Product/info" use="@prodId"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Products/Product/List">

      <xsl:variable name="tprodId" select="@prodId"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
        <xsl:attribute name="sellId">
                 <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $tprodId)/@sellId"/>
              </xsl:attribute>                  
      </xsl:for-each>      

  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="List" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tprodId" select="@prodId"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $tprodId)/@sellId"/>                
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="@sellId" >
    <xsl:variable name="tprodId" select="../@prodId"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $tprodId)/@sellId"/>                
    </xsl:for-each>         
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: why did you strip out everything from xpath? for Simplicity? 
(because the above example is simplified version and I can have multiple nodes )

It also fails: runtime error: file copy.xsl line 12 element copy
Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element.

Comment: @yuris If you have multiple `List` elements in different branches of the tree, then - and only then - you need to make the match pattern specific enough to distinguish between them.

Comment: your first example yields  this:
`runtime error: file my.xsl line 12 element copy
Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element.
runtime error: file my.xsl line 12 element copy
Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element.
runtime error: file my.xsl line 23 element copy-of
Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element.`

Comment: @yuris I had inadvertently copied the wrong template. Try it now.