# Copy attributes from child nodes to a child node of matching nodes in two xmls

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a [followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251392/matching-and-updating-attributes-in-2-xmls) question.

This time I have a child node in xml2 with attributes that I need to copy.

XML1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
   <Product prodId="123456" sellId="" colorId="">                
            <Supplier id="" name=""/>
            <Misc lib="" />                    
   </Product>
</Products>
```

XML2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <info prodId="123456" sellId="121" colorId="AD3">         
            <qnty lib="34">4</qnty>
        </info>
        <info prodId="23456" sellId="890" colorId="BM7">          
            <qnty lib="2">1</qnty>
        </info>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

This time, 'lib' attribute of node 'qnty' of xml2 should go to 'lib' attribute of node 'Misc'.

Now, my template, searches

```
<xsl:param name="f1" select="'xml2.xml'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($f1)"/>

        <xsl:key name="k1" match="Products/Product/info" use="@prodId"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Products/Product" >
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="@prodId"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/@sellId"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/@colorId"/>                                

                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Products/Product/Misc"/>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/qnty/@lib"/>        
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
```

'lib' attribute is added to 'Product' node, and not to child 'Misc' node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this, not sure it's the best solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="f1" select="'xml2.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($f1)"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="Products/Product/info" use="@prodId"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Products/Product" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="@prodId"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/@sellId"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/@colorId"/>                                             
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Products/Product/Misc" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="../@prodId"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">                                               
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', $prodId)/qnty/@lib"/>    
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```